# Accessing CSV row value by another value

Tags: python, csv

Considering the following CSV data, how can I access the `For Sale Amount` value of a specific row by its `ID`?

```
Title,Price,For Sale Amount,Link,ID,Date Added
"First Sample Item",$358.35,2,https://www.website.com/release/FOO,FOO,Jul-09-2022 15:52:40
"Second Sample Item",$7.68,2,https://www.website.com/release/BAR,BAR,Jul-09-2022 15:52:40
```

I'm accessing the data from a local file as follows:

```
# Create file if it doesn't exist, write headers to it
if not Path(csv_file_location).is_file():
  with open(csv_file_location, 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write('Title,Price,For Sale Amount,Link,ID,Date Added\n')

# Re-open the file for reading, which now must exist, and has headers
with open(csv_file_location, 'r+', newline='') as csv_file:
  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
  field_names = next(csv_reader) # Skip headers
  csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

  existing_for_sale_ids = [id[4] for id in csv_reader] # Read for sale list, store IDs

  # Loop through release links list
  for link in RELEASE_LINKS:
    response = session.get(link)
    for_sale = response.html.find('#release-marketplace .forsale_QoVFl > a', first=True)

    # If item is for sale
    if for_sale:
      for_sale_title = response.html.find('title', first=True).text.replace(' - Discogs', '').replace('–', '-')
      for_sale_price = response.html.find('#release-marketplace .price_2Wkos', first=True).text
      for_sale_amount = for_sale.text.split(' ')[0]
      for_sale_link = link
      for_sale_id = link.split('/')[4].split('-')[0]
      for_sale_info = [for_sale_title, for_sale_price, for_sale_amount, for_sale_link, for_sale_id, date_time]

      # If for sale ID is not in CSV
      if for_sale_id not in existing_for_sale_ids:
        csv_writer.writerow(for_sale_info)

        for_sale_info_formatted = f'{for_sale_title} - {for_sale_price}\n{for_sale_link}'

        send_email(for_sale_title, for_sale_info_formatted)
```

Comment: if you can use other python packages, try using "pandas" package, which is specifically built for table operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really inclined to do it using the csv module, here you go.

```
import csv

with open('random_csv.csv', 'r') as fr:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(fr)
    for_sale_by_ID = {col['ID'] : col['For Sale Amount'] for col in csvreader}
    
print(for_sale_by_ID)

# To access specific For Sale Amounts:
for_sale_amount_FOO = for_sale_by_ID['FOO']
print(f'FOO for sale amount : {for_sale_amount_FOO}')
```

Output:

```
{'FOO': '2', 'BAR': '2'}
FOO for sale amount : 2
```

However, for more tedious extractions, using the `pandas` module is much more efficient.

Update:

By "I need to compare the link's existing For Sale Amount with the one that gets scraped in the if for_sale: condition.", I am assuming you want to compare the ID's for_sale_amount in the `csv_file` if it already exists to the one you just scraped in the loop. If I understood this wrong, please correct me.

I have a few comments about this.

1. You are not updating your `existing_for_sale_ids` list everytime you're writing to the csv_file. You have to do this either by reading the `csv_file` from the beginning (get the file pointer to 0 using `seek()`) or by appending the new `ID` to the list when you're writing to the file.
2. You can also gather the `For Sale Amounts` with the IDs simultaneously as you're going to need that to compare. You can do this using the method I mentioned previously using `csv.DictReader()` or like this

```
csvreader = csv.reader(csv_file)
next(csvreader)
existing_info = {row[4] : row[2] for row in csvreader}
```

3. Now in the for loop create an if-else statement

```
if for_sale_id in existing_info.keys():
    same_price = for_sale_price == existing_info[for_sale_id]
    if not same_price:
        # do whatever you have to
else:
    csvwriter.writerow(for_sale_info)
    existing_info[for_sale_id] = for_sale_price # Updating the dict
```

As I said, you can also update the `existing_dict` by re-reading the file from the beginning. Whatever you feel comfortable with.
I only added snippets here. If there's something you didn't understand, comment it out.
Again, I am assuming you want to compare the scraped `for_sale_price` with the already existing `for_sale_price` for a particular `ID`. Let me know if I got this wrong.

Comment: I didn't mind using `pandas`, but it turns out that it didn't work because I need to access the value immediately after it's written to the CSV file, which `pandas` didn't let me do. I tried this option, but it doesn't quite work since I'm using `csv,reader()` at the moment with `next()` to skip the headers.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Give me an idea so I may help. What are you writing to the csv file and what are you trying to access after writing?

Comment: Sure. I updated my question with the rest of my script, which scrapes data on a website and conditionally writes it to a local CSV file. In the same logic, I'm trying to access the `For Sale Amount` value for rows based on their `ID`. I need to compare the `link`'s existing `For Sale Amount` with the one that gets scraped in the `if for_sale:` condition.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. The `if not same_price:` should be in the `else` for my purpose, but it's working as expected now. I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

If you can use other python packages, try this approach:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_location)
print(df.loc[df['ID']=='FOO',['For Sale Amount']])
```

If package is not available, you can install by using below pip install command in the terminal: `pip install pandas`

Hope it helps!

Code tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['FOO','BAR','COOL'], "For Sale Amount":[200, 300, 500], "Col3": [89,90,91]})

print(df.loc[df['ID']=='FOO', ['For Sale Amount']])
```

Output:

```
For Sale Amount
0              200
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like exactly what I need, but I'm getting this error: ```Empty DataFrame
Columns: [For Sale Amount]
Index: []```

Comment: @MarioParra - added the code I ran & it's output

Comment: I get the same output for the hardcoded table, but unfortunately, it doesn't help with the error on my CSV file.

Comment: If I `print (pd.read_csv(csv_file_location))`, I see my CSV file data too